# Read table into R with Extra Quotes in Strings

Tags: r, string, element, double-quotes, read.table

I have a tab-delimited file that I am trying to read into R. String variables are denoted with double quotes, however, there are additional double quotes inside some of the strings themselves:

[image]

There are also coordinates in some of the string variables that produce the same issue of quotes inside the string:

[image]

When trying to read into R, it provide the following error:
`"Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : line 237 did not have 55 elements."`

How can I read these files into R without having it split up the string? Alternatively, is there a way to save the source data differently so that this issue does not occur when reading into R?

Comment: (1) *"trying to read into R"*, using what code? There are at least four methods (base, `readr`, `data.table::fread`, `vroom::vroom`), each with their own nuances (and limitations). (2) It would be far simpler to test this with an actual reproducible example, and I don't mean asking us to scrape images of your data. Please provide a reduced sample data, perhaps 2-3 rows and 2-3 columns, as literal text (in a code block). Thanks.

Comment: If you are using `read.table`, you might try `data.table::fread`, it appears to have different quote-interpretation.

Comment: Maybe using `read_files()` and stringr library to replace the double quotes with single ones. It's difficult to tell without the actual data, or a sample of it.